# R Loop from df to search in PostgreSQL

Tags: r, postgresql, loops

PostgreSQL table structure looks like

```
if (!dbExistsTable(pg, c("store", "a"))) {
  dbGetQuery(pg, "
             CREATE TABLE a (
    company_name text,
    num text,
    date date,
    file text
    )
    ")
}
```

and R dataframe is

```
df <- data.frame(num=c('13','15', '100', '700'))
```

what i want is to search df column num (all rows) from PostgreSQL something like

```
file.list <- dbGetQuery(pg, "
    SET work_mem='1GB';

    SELECT *
    FROM store.a
    WHERE num = ?????
")
```

don't know how to create where clause for the loop to get the desired results and is it possible to fixed the results for specific date/year?

Comment: 1)in sql,columns dont *have* numbers, if you want to refer to columns by number (a bad idea,IMO), you'll have to do that in`R` 2) The sql-interface only allows one statement per call, use a separate call for the (useless) `SET work_mem= ...` 3) you need prepared statements for your parameters.

Comment: yap i just pushed R data frame into PostgreSQL table and then matched two tables to get the desired output.